# How can I improve my question on the factorial formula?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I thought I asked a [decent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4702849/struggling-to-intuitively-understand-the-factorial-formula) but it has been downvoted. I don't know how I can improve it. Please provide suggestions.

Comment: Don't worry too much about the anonymous downvotes because no one except the downvoter can tell the reason for the vote. In your specific example you can see a reasonable number of helpful comments and you should focus on them.

Comment: In any case I can see that you have tried to explain your problem/confusion and have also given feedback to a commenter. Good job there. +1 for your question on main site.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thanks again